# Post multiple form field data to 3rd party server after Google Invisible reCaptcha success?

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha, pardot

So I am new to this so please excuse me if my question is not posted as expected. Any suggestions and advice will be kindly appreciated.

So I have a form with multiple fields that posts to an PHP file that verifies an Invisible Google reCAPTCHA and then proceeds to post to Pardot (third party software that notifies our sales team)

Following this post [How to Post Form Data to 3rd Party Server After Google Invisible reCaptcha Success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024881/how-to-post-form-data-to-3rd-party-server-after-google-invisible-recaptcha-succe)
I can successfully send the email form field to Pardot but I can not seem to send any other fields and/or replace the email field with another one.
In other words I have two fields name="firstname" and name="email" when I send the email field it posts but if I change "email" to "firstname" in the PHP it does not fire.

Based on what I have read I am relatively sure I will need to create an array on the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS section of my PHP that currently only sends one value ($pardotPost) but before I attempt to send an array I wanted to test the other form fields to see if works as mentioned above.

Here is my client side markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>

    <style>
      input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
        /* insert your own styles for invalid form input */
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        color: red!important;
      }

      input:required:valid {
        /* insert your own styles for valid form input */
        color: green!important;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
      function onSubmit(token) {
        document.getElementById("pardot-form-full-width").submit();
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="mn-call-form-wrapper">

    <form id="pardot-form-full-width"
          class="uk-form uk-grid-medium uk-form-horizontal invisible-recaptcha"
          action="reCAPTCHA.php"
          method="POST"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          uk-grid>

      <!-- First Name -->
      <div class="uk-width-1-2@s">
        <input placeholder="First Name *"
               class="mix-contact-form-item uk-input"
               type="text"
               id="firstname"
               name="firstname"
               required=”required”/>
      </div>
      <!-- END - First Name -->

      <!-- Email Address -->
      <div class="uk-width-1-2@s">
        <input placeholder="Email *"
               class="mix-contact-form-item uk-input"
               type="email"
               id="email"
               name="email"
               required="required"/>
      </div>
      <!-- END - Email Address -->

      <!-- Submit Button -->
      <div class="mix-signup-submit-button-wrapper">
        <button class="g-recaptcha"
                data-sitekey="myGrecaptchaKeyIsHere"
                data-callback="onSubmit"> Send <span uk-icon="arrow-right" class="uk-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- END - Submit Button -->

    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my server side markup (reCAPTCHA.php):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        // reCaptcha info
        $secret = "mySecretKey";
        $remoteip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

        // Form info
        $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
        $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

        // Curl Request
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'secret' => $secret,
            'response' => $response,
            'remoteip' => $remoteip
            ));
        $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        // Parse data
        $recaptcha = json_decode($curlData, true);

        if ($recaptcha["success"]) {
            echo "Thank you, we will be in contact with you soon.";

            $pardotPost ='firstname='. $_POST["firstname"];
            $curl_handle = curl_init();
            $url = "http://pardot.com/our/url";
            curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pardotPost);
            curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
            $result = curl_exec ($curl_handle);
            curl_close ($curl_handle);
        }

        else {
            echo "Oh no, it seems something went wrong.";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the PHP sections below if I change the values from firstname to email I can confirm the data is sent and ingested by Pardot

```
// Does not work
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$pardotPost ='firstname='. $_POST["firstname"];

// Does work
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pardotPost ='email='. $_POST["email"];
```

So my question is two parts.
One - why does the form submit if the email value is used and secondly how would I go about adding several other form fields and send them to Pardot after successful (invisible) Google reCAPTCHA validation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this seems to work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        // reCaptcha info
        $secret = "key-goes-here";
        $remoteip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

        // Form info
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
        $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        $querytype = $_POST["querytype"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $termsconditionsfw = $_POST["termsconditionsfw"];
        $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

        // Curl Request
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'secret' => $secret,
            'response' => $response,
            'remoteip' => $remoteip
            ));
        $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        // Parse data
        $recaptcha = json_decode($curlData, true);

        if ($recaptcha["success"]) {
            echo "Thank you, we will be in contact with you soon.";

            //extract data from the post
            //set POST variables
            $url = 'http://explore.mixtelematics.com/l/69882/2019-01-15/d3zr3d';
            $fields = array(
              'email' => urlencode($_POST['email']),
             'firstname' => urlencode($_POST['firstname']),
             'lastname' => urlencode($_POST['lastname']),
             'phone' => urlencode($_POST['phone']),
             'querytype' => urlencode($_POST['querytype']),
             'message' => urlencode($_POST['message']),
             'termsconditionsfw' => urlencode($_POST['termsconditionsfw']),
            );

            //url-ify the data for the POST
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            rtrim($fields_string, '&');

            //open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

            //execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            //close connection
            curl_close($ch);
        }

        else {
            echo "Oh no, it seems something went wrong.";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I submit this, it sends the information to Pardot :)

Comment: I can confirm this works and uses a invis google recaptcha. About to go live with this update after I added some validation and a redirect flow. Let me know if any of you out there using Pardot need some help :)